# Link several modules at once - IBM DOORS

Tags: websphere, ibm-doors

I have one module which needs to be linked, through the same link module, to several modules. What would be the fastest way to do that?
Right now, I'm linking manually each module and I need to select the target module and link module every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use DXL, you could use Link->Advanced->Link By Attribute.

You would create a (temporary?) attribute in the outgoing module which contains the ID(s) of the requirement(s) you want to link to. Perhaps you need to apply a filter depending on your needs. Then you start "Link By Attribute" for each Link Module and for each Destination Module. That should be way faster than linking each and every object by hand.